# Why Does a Torus Require Four Patches to Cover?

Tags: differential-geometry

The book I'm reading implies at least four coordinate patches (simple surfaces) are needed to cover a torus. Consider the following mapping:

> $$\textbf{x}(u^1, u^2) =  \begin{bmatrix} ((2+cos(u^1))cos(u^2) \\
>  ((2+cos(u^1))sin(u^2) \\ sin(u^1) \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> where $u^1, u^2 \in(-\pi, \pi)$.

The issue here is we are missing the points when $u^1,u^2 =\pm\pi$. Geometrically, we are missing the points on a circle lining the inside of the torus, and another circle orthogonal to the aforementioned one, that does not line the inside of torus but rather goes about the "tube" part. Why can't we then just use the same mapping as above but with $u^1, u^2\in(0, 2\pi)$?

Comment: Those two patches cover the whole thing?

Comment: note that using two pieces like that will still miss some points: namely $(u^1, u^2) = (\pi, 0)$ and $(u^1, u^2) = (0, \pi)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No, they don't. Visually I thought they did.

Comment: @RolfHoyer Thanks! A little embarrassed that I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

There is an atlas for the $2$-torus $T$ with three charts. If we view $T$ as the result of doing identifications as usual on a square $Q$, then the three open sets are

- the complement of the image in $T$ of the horizontal sides of $Q$,
- the complement of the imagfe in $T$ of the vertical sides of $Q$, and
- a small disk in $T$ centered at the image of the vertices of $Q$.

These are two annuli and a disk.

I am pretty sure you cannot do this with with two charts. If one adds the requirement that the domains of the charts are contractible, this follows from the theory of Lusternik–Schnirelmann category and its lower bound in terms of cup length. But of course, two of my open sets above are not contractible...

Comment: we view the 2-torus as an open square complemented with one horizontal and one vertical edge, each self-replicated on the other side, those correspond to 3 local-homeomorphisms

Comment: @user1952009, I have no idea what you are trying to say :-|

Comment: You can cover a torus with just two annuli, no?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, well… how?

Comment: If you cover $S^1$ with two intervals $I_1, I_2$ then the annuli $I_1 \times S^1, I_2 \times S^1$ cover $S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: (intuitively, a torus is an open square complemented with 2 edges $=$ 3 charts) $ \quad$ I don't get what Anthony means. $3$ is optimal or not ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, three charts are enough even if we require them to be contractible.
Identify $\mathbb T^2=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, then we can use charts $(0,1)^2,(-0.5,0.5)^2,(0.3,1.3)^2$ with the quotient map as chart map to cover it. Since the quotient map is proper on it, it is a closed map, so the quotient map is a topological embedding. They forms a chart. The only points missed by the first chart is $(0,t),(t,0)$. After the second chart, we only need to cover $(0,t),(t,0)(t\ge 0.5)$. The third chart covers it, so we are done.
Two noncontractible charts is also ok.$B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S^1\times R}$, and two the latter set cover the torus by $\mathbb S^1\times(0,2\pi)\mathrm{ or }(-\pi,\pi)$.
Two contractible or simply connected should be not sufficient. Maybe we can adjust the intersection to be connected and use Van-Kapmen, but I don't know how.